How to add select dropdown filters
Summary of problem or feature request
I am trying to add 3 filters (Status, From, To). How can I do that using the Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable class?
Code snippet of problem
<?php

namespace App\DataTables\Payments;

use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\Payment;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Button;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Column;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;

class BankTransferDataTable extends DataTable
{
    protected $exportColumns = [
        'id', 'order_id', 'order_number', 'invoice_number', 'bulk_order_key',
        'add_on', 'email', 'mobile_number', 'g_bank', 'bank_name', 'account_name',
        'account_number', 'payment_date', 'amount', 'deposit_slip', 'status',
        'transaction_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'phone', 'order_status', 'order_total'
    ];

    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        return datatables()
            ->eloquent($query)
            // ->filter(function ($query) {
            //  if (request()->has('search')) {
            //      $query->where(function($query) {
            //          $query->where('categories.name', 'LIKE', '%' . request('search')['value'] . '%')
            //          ->orWhere('categories.slug', 'LIKE', '%' . request('search')['value'] . '%');
            //      }); 
            //  }
            // })
            ->addColumn('Order #', function ($payment) {
                return $payment->bulk_order_key;
            })
            ->addColumn('Gifted Account', function ($payment) {
                return $payment->g_bank;
            })
            ->addColumn('Bank Name', function ($payment) {
                return $payment->bank_name;
            })
            ->addColumn('Account Name', function ($payment) {
                return $payment->account_name;
            })
            ->addColumn('Status', function ($payment) {
                if ($payment->transaction_id) {
                    return $payment->get_wallet_transaction_status();
                } else if($payment->bulk_order_key) {
                    $orderStatus = Order::select(['status'])
                        ->where('bulk_order_key', $payment->bulk_order_key)
                        ->first();

                    if ($orderStatus) {
                        return $orderStatus->status;
                    }
                }

                return $payment->order_status;
            });
            // ->addColumn('Actions', function ($category) {
            //  return view('backend.catalog.categories.action', compact('category'));
            // });
    }

    /**
     * Get query source of dataTable.
     *
     * @param  \App\Payment  $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function query(Payment $model)
    {
        $filters = request()->has('search.value') && filled(request('search.value')) ? json_decode(request('search.value'), true)['filters'] : [];

        return $model->newQuery()
            ->selectRaw('payments.*, orders.phone, orders.status as order_status, orders.total as order_total')
            ->leftJoin('orders', 'payments.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
            ->whereRaw('payments.bulk_order_key <> ""');

            if (filled($filters['status'])) {
                $query->where('payments.status', $filters['status']);
            }

            $query->when((request()->has('from') && request()->has('to')), function ($query) {
                $query->whereDate('payments.created_at', '>=', request()->get('from'));
                $query->whereDate('payments.created_at', '<=', request()->get('to'));
            })
            ->when((request()->has('from')), function ($query) {
                $query->whereDate('payments.created_at', '>=', request()->get('from'));
                $query->whereDate('payments.created_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today')));
            })
            ->when((request()->has('to')), function ($query) {
                $query->whereDate('payments.created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-5 years')));
                $query->whereDate('payments.created_at', '<=', request()->get('to'));
            })
            ->orderBy('payments.created_at', 'desc');
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder
     */
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->setTableId('bankTransferPaymentsTable')
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
            ->minifiedAjax()
            ->dom('Brtip')
            ->orderBy(1)
            ->buttons(
                Button::make('export')->buttons(['csv']),
                Button::make('reset')
                    ->text('<span><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> Refresh</span>'),
            );
    }

    /**
     * Get columns.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            Column::make('Order #'),
            Column::make('Gifted Account'),
            Column::make('Bank Name'),
            Column::make('Status'),
            // Column::make('Actions')
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get filename for export.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function filename()
    {
        return 'bank_transfer_payments_report_' . date('YmdHis');
    }
}


And for the view:
{{ $dataTable->scripts() }}

<script>
    $(function () {
        const filter = () => {
            const filters = {
                filters: {
                    status: $('#filterStatus').val()
                }
            };

            // window.LaravelDataTables["bankTransferPaymentsTable"].destroy();

            window.LaravelDataTables["bankTransferPaymentsTable"].search(JSON.stringify(filters)).draw();
                
            $('#bankTransferPaymentsTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        };

        $(document).on('change', '#filterStatus', function() {
            filter();
        });
    });
</script>

Filters screenshot

Issue
When selecting status from the dropdown, the table data is not refreshing/reloading. I am not also getting any output from the console.
System details

Operating System: MacOS
PHP Version: 8.1
Laravel Version: 8.83.27
Laravel-Datatables Version: 9.11


I think you are on the right path. It seems you have put the required code after the return statement in function query(). Maybe if you make sure your code is not returning there, you actually run the rest of the queries :)

@Techno You're right! :) Please add your answer so I can mark as answer. it's working now

I've added the answer, thanks :)

Seems like there is a return statement in your code preventing your code (thats after the return) to be executed:
public function query(Payment $model)
    {
        $filters = request()->has('search.value') && filled(request('search.value')) ? json_decode(request('search.value'), true)['filters'] : [];

        return $model->newQuery() //Change this here and it should be solved :)
            ->selectRaw('payments.*, orders.phone, orders.status as order_status, orders.total as order_total')
            ->leftJoin('orders', 'payments.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
            ->whereRaw('payments.bulk_order_key <> ""');

           //... rest of code
    }


